# $a_1^k+\cdots+a_n^k=0$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Prove that for $a_i\in F$ where $F$ is an algebraically closed field (Edit:with characteristic $0$), say $\mathbb C$, if $a_1^k+\cdots+a_n^k=0$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$, then $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$.

For now the answer I know either use Newton's identity or Vandermonde determinant, which both seem overkill. I think maybe we could argue that the equations are linearly independent so it has at most one solution, or use induction somehow. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the assumption implies

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1-(a_i X)^{n+1}}{1-a_i X} = n. $$

Multiplying $(1-a_1 X)\cdots(1-a_n X)$ to both sides,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(1-(a_i X)^{n+1}\right)\prod_{\substack{1 \leq j \leq n \\ j \neq i}} (1 - a_j X) = n(1-a_1 X)\cdots(1-a_n X). $$

Comparing the coefficients of $X^n$ and using that $\operatorname{char}(F) = 0$, we have $a_1 \cdots a_n = 0$ and hence $a_i = 0$ for some $i$. This allow us to initiate induction.